# How can I display items from a database based on a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display text using PHP from a database (an issue) and then the user will click a button and integers will be added to that users statistics.

**Here's the problem (in short):**

I would like to have a variable (`$count`) that (e.g: `if $count = 1`) would display the text (issue) with that ID from the database. 
However, when the user clicks one of the buttons - I want it so that the count is increased by one, the user can go off the site - and when the user returns it will still display the most recent issue (`not $count = 1`, but `$count = 2`)

**Here's what I have tried:**

I feel like I am able to actually do the selecting from a database, but when I used `$count = 0;` at the start of the page - and then once the user clicked a button that led to `$count = 1;` - However, when the user refreshed the page it would go back to `$count = 0;` (obviously) -- instead of `$count = 1;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150944/variable-persistence-in-php

Comment: Thank you so much!