# how to add to an array and not change it's first value?

Tags: php, arrays, addition, cart

hey there so basically i'm trying to make a cart and i want the id products to be in a array so that i can serialize them in a cookie for 15 days, the problem i that each time i press the button "add to cart" it changes the previous id instead of adding to the array, i've tried making a loop and changing the index each time and i've tried just adding with `$cart[]=$itemId;` and the `array_push();` function, nothing seems to work.

```
    if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $panier = array();
    $panier[] = $item;
    print_r($panier);
    }
```

Just to explain the code, this code will be used when the add to cart button is pressed and retain the product id from the post variable and then add to the array each time but instead i only get a single value in the array that keeps changing everytime i press the button to add.

Comment: PHP is stateless. You will need to revive the state of the cart by (de)serializing it either through a session or a cookie. The latter of which you're already suggesting to use, but evidently not yet are using. Which leaves me a a bit confused about what your question really is?

Comment: i only talked about the serialize to explain what i want to do next, but at this point i'm really just trying to make my array

Comment: You'll likely want to validate/filter that value before you add it to your array/storage.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're creating a new array each time and then just adding one value to it. Remove `$panier = array()` to avoid creating a new array each time.

Combining @IncredibleHat's suggestion into working example:

```
$item = 0;
while($item <= 5) {
    if (!isset($panier)) { $panier = array(); }
    $panier[] = $item;
    $item++;
}

print_r($panier);
```

Notice that if you remove the `if(!isset($panier)`, then `$panier` only ends up containing the last value, because it gets re-initialised to empty every iteration through the loop.

Comment: Or wrap it in a condition: `if (!isset($panier)) { $panier = array(); }`

Comment: That's not going to help in this situation, as the PHP page code containing this page is newly requested every time the button is clicked.

Comment: thanks for your answer but even after removing that part it still does the same thing, any idea?

Comment: Then you need to persist the `$panier` variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150944/variable-persistence-in-php

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not using storage that persists between requests, your method prevents people buying more than one of an item:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    $_SESSION['panier'][$_POST['item']]=
      isset($_SESSION['panier'][$_POST['item']) ?
      $_SESSION['panier'][$_POST['item']] + 1   :
      1;
 }
```